# Debugger reports value of BOOL block argument as NO, but my if statement evaluates true

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging, objective-c-blocks

I am calling a block with a boolean value. According to the debugger, the boolean value is false, but it seems to be treated as true. Is this a compiler/Xcode bug, or am I supposed to mark the parameters being passed to a block in some way similar to `__block`?

```
// Hovering over the |finished| parameter displays the value of finished as NO
[self.repDataSynchronizationClient synchronizeWithRepId:rep.id andCompletion:^(NSString * progressMessage, BOOL finished){
    if( finished )
    {
        [self hideLoader];    // Breakpoint set here, which I am hitting
    }
    else
    {
        [self setLoaderTitle:progressMessage];
    }
}];
```

Here's [a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PV4Kd.png) of the situation, with the breakpoint hit and tooltip displayed.

Comment: Another option is that it could be a bug in the debugger (i.e. the value shown in the popup may be wrong).

Comment: I don't see the error. The popup says it's `NO`, you also say it's false, where's the contradiction?

Comment: @H2CO3 If the value is NO, then it should not go through the if statement.

Comment: @aryaxt The debugger shows the next line after the breakpoint, I still se no problem.

Comment: @H2CO3 Do you see the popup that says stopped at breakpoint? That means the debugger has got to that line, which is wrong because the only way it should get there is if the boolean is set to YES

Comment: Please put code into your question _as text_.

Comment: @JoshCaswell The problem related to the XCode error, not particularly the code. The image was well suited to the question

Comment: @james: I've left a link to the screenshot, and added text to indicate what's happening with Xcode. I think this is a million times easier to read.

Comment: The poor image formatting of SO squashing the content was the only gripe I had with the question before. The OP had provided a link to the image to help.

Comment: ... Though I think the question is well formatted as it is now too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are in release rather than debug, there is a strong probability that it just the **breakpoints that are wrong**. This is presumably due to the complier removing some statements in release as in optimises and line numbers no longer lining up with the code they are supposed to.

Verify which clause your if statement is reaching with `NSLog` statements instead.

---

On a separate note, you mention the use of `__block`, but don't actually use it and appear to have a retain cycle there. It should probably read:

```
__block id selfReference = self;
[self.repDataSynchronizationClient synchronizeWithRepId:rep.id andCompletion:^(NSString* message, BOOL finished) {
    if (finished)
    {
        [selfReference hideLoader];
    }
    else 
    {
        [selfReference setLoaderTitle:progressMessage];
    }
}];
```

If using ARC, use `__unsafe_unretained` instead of `__block`.

Comment: Thanks to your edit, I spent hours yesterday figuring out why my ViewControllers were leaking, and your comment helped fix all those leaks. I used __unsafe_unretained instead of __block

Comment: Glad I could help. =] I added the ARC reference to my answer too

Comment: This is not necessarily a problematic retain cycle; ***only*** if the Block will not be deallocated before `self` is there a problem. Since this is just a completion handler, it's doubtful that `repDataSynchronizationClient` is actually copying it. Therefore, it's on the stack, and the cycle will be broken as soon as `synchronizeWithRepId:andCompletion:` finishes.